# How do I wire half hot receptacle to 2 switches?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, multiway-switch

I am trying to wire a half hot receptacle to 2 switches on opposite walls. One switch is already wired and working with the receptacle using 14/3 cable. The single pole switch has hot (black wire) on top, red on bottom, and neutral (white) married to other neutrals in the wall box. I have a 14/3 from opposite wall already wired into the same wall box.

How do I correctly wire in the wall box and to the opposite wall switch so that it can toggle receptacle on/off, with the power source at the original wall box? I tried it by pigtailing reds, neutrals, and black at the wall box. At the opposite wall switch I wired black on top, red on bottom and capped the neutral. This didn't work, as the switches work independently of one another but will not toggle each other on/off.

Answer (score 1):

#### Three-Way Switches

You have standard toggle switches. You need **three-way switches**. A standard switches on/off. A three-way switch switches one *common* wire to alternate between two other *traveler* wires. Pretty much any standard toggle switch can be replaced with a 3-way switch - regular, Decora, etc. The most important thing is running 14/3 (or 12/3 on a 20A circuit) between the switches instead of 14/2, but you did that.

There are a few different ways that these switches can be wired. This is specific to your particular configuration. Note that there is no standard for where the screws are on switches! On a standard switch, it doesn't matter which wire goes to which screw. on a 3-way switch, it does matter. The instructions should make it clear, but pretty universal is that there will be different colors - one screw (= common) silver and two screws brass (= travelers) (or vice versa). I will refer to them as common and travelers, as that is what matters, no location or color.

- Original switch box:

  - Old Black = hot = *common* screw on replacement 3-way switch.
  - Old Red = switched hot = white wire coming from new switch box.
  - Old White = neutral = still passes through, as currently connected to other neutrals.
  - New Black = traveler = *traveler* screw on replacement 3-way switch.
    New Red = traveler = *traveler* screw on replacement 3-way switch.
- New switch box. Replace standard switch with 3-way switch as follows:

  - Black = *traveler* screw
  - Red = *traveler* screw
  - White = *common* screw

#### White vs. Neutral

There is one more complication. Neutral and white are normally the same thing. A *switch loop* is an exception. In recent versions of the NEC, *most* switch boxes need to have neutral in a box, *for new work*. With a regular switch loop (one switch), the solution is to use /3 cable instead of /2, so that you have Black = hot, Red = switched hot, White = neutral. But with a 3-way switch, you need 3 wires so that means going to /4 cable, which is not nearly as common. If this were an existing circuit then this would not be an issue. But the 3-way 2nd-switch is brand new here, so grandfathering does not solve the problem.

I **think** you are OK here because one of the switch boxes in the circuit has neutral. But I am not 100% certain. If it turns out that you need a neutral in **both** boxes then you will either need /4 cable or use smart switches instead.

Assuming that you are allowed to use white as a common switched-hot wire, then you need to mark both ends of the wire (e.g., colored, but not green or white, electrical tape) to make it clear that this white wire is *not* neutral.

Comment: You are correct that neutral is only required at one location in a multi-way switch complex

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work and tripped the breaker.

Comment: Can you upload pictures of the switch boxes?